# Date pattern doesn't work as expected in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk

I am trying to use following date filter to convert string to date but it doesn't seem to be working.

Sample input data(string) - Mon Jan 20 09:20:35 GMT 2020

I am first using a mutate gsub to remove GMT which renders following string output-
Mon Jan 20 09:20:35 2020

My gsub mutate filter looks like this -

```
mutate { gsub => [ "TimeStamp", "GMT", "" ] }
```

Now, I am using a date filter to convert gsub output to date format but it doesn't seem to be working-

```
date {
match => [ "TimeStamp", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss  yyyy" ]
target => "TimeStamp"
locale => "en"
}
```

I have also tried following with no success-

```
date {
match => [ "TimeStamp", "EEE\sMMM\sdd\sHH:mm:ss\s+yyyy" ]
target => "TimeStamp"
timezone => "Etc/GMT"
locale => "en"
}
```

Comment: Why is there that `EEE`? According to the doc, it's for the abbreviated day of the week and I'm not seeing any in your sample data.

Comment: Sorry there was typo in in the original date string. It indeed has a weekday.

Answer (score 2):

The date pattern should be

> MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy

Maybe you have to add some extra spaces before the year (looks like you have them in your logs).

Instead of EEE (name of weekday abreviated) you need to use MMM (name of month abreviated).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there was a typo in in the original date string I posted. It indeed has a weekday.

Comment: @user2242660 the pattern looks correct. I think the whitespaces produced by the gsub are causing the problems. Why do you want to remove the timezone at all? You could enhance the pattern by specifying the timezone like so: *EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy*. See http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html for all valid timezones and abbreviations.

Comment: @user2242660 have you had success with the enhanced date pattern?

Comment: Thanks again. Actually there was no issue with the filter, I needed to recreate the index (delete all the old indices and create a new one) as the same field was being used in the old indices with a different data type. Also, your suggestion about not using gsub and matching the timezone with ZZZ also works fine.